# proper procedure to repair RAID 1 volume in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: raid, software-raid

I'ave a windows server r2 with the following configuration

- 500mb SATA for OS
- 2 x 1TB SATA in Software Raid 1 (done through the operating system)

One of the 1TB drives are bad.

1. What will happen when I just unplug and remove the bad drive?
2. Do I have to do anything to just use the 1 good drive while I wait for the dead one to be RMA'd?
3. how do I restore the Raid 1 configuration once I receive the replacement drive?